# Setting up Debian local server on specific port

Tags: linux, networking, debian, iptables

I'm trying to set up a local web server using the port 8000 to be accessed from an internal LAN network in order to test a web application.

The problem is I'm not sure how to do it.
I created two iptables rules (INPUT and OUTPUT) like below:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:8000 state NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:8000 state ESTABLISHED
```

But when I execute nmap from a machine connected to the same LAN using the local ip address of the server (the one is shown by ifconfig command) to check the which ports are listening, 8000 port isn't listed.

```
nmap -v -sT local_ip_address
```

I guess I'm missing some step or doing something wrong creating the rules.

Any ideas?

Comment: The INPUT chain rule should have 8000 as the destination port not the source port. Not that it matters since `policy ACCEPT` will accept all packets unless specifically dropped.

Answer (score 0):

Is the service (I'm amusing [apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html)) configured to run on port 8000?

Comment: Yes, I'm running a Django server. But even with it is not working